# How to resolve libc++abi.dylib error for swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For some reason I am getting an error whenever I run FirebaseApp.configure() in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method. But when I run FirebaseApp.configure() in an init, it works just fine. Why is that? The error I'm getting is

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The reason why I want to run FirebaseApp.configure() in my applicaitonDidFinishLaunching method is because I'm trying to setup firebase cloud messaging. It's currently not working but what I realized after I created a new demo app from scratch is that it works just fine if FirebaseApp.configure() is in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method but it doesnt work if I put it in the init method.

I also get the same error if I never call FirebaseApp.configure().

Here is my podfile

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ArcadeCity' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for ArcadeCity
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '= 2.3.0'
end
```

And here is my app delegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
import FBSDKCoreKit
import GoogleMaps

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

override init() {
    super.init()
    //FirebaseApp.configure()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAJxvbSc0wd1jJYCpqEC0iAB4PPlMu03UE")
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red:0.02, green:0.44, blue:0.75, alpha:1.0)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")\nend")
    return true
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}

// Called when APNs has assigned the device a unique token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
    Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "newRideRequests")
}

// Called when APNs failed to register the device for push notifications
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // Print the error to console (you should alert the user that registration failed)
    print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ArcadeCity")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you get anything in the debugging console before that error message? If so, please post it here. There could be some hint there, e.g. if this is  related to the Google Service info plist not being included.

Comment: I am not getting anything else in the console. I have also tried downloading a new google service info plist and adding it into my project in many different ways and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't inadvertently calling `FirebaseApp.configure()` more than once, as calling it more than that results in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was due to me not understanding the app lifecycle. Elsewhere in my app, I was making a reference to the firebase database. Turns out that code ran before my "applicationDidFinishLaunching". Here I was thinking the "didFinishLaunching" method was for low level stuff and that it would run before any of my own personal code ran. Not the case at all.